# Assembler with C - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, assembly, linker, segmentation-fault

I have two files: f1.S where is my Fibonacci function (counts n-th member of Fibonacci sequence) written in assembler language and f2.c where the Fibonacci function is called.

Here are these files:
f1.S

```
.global fibonacci
fibonacci:

push %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
push %rax

movq 16(%rbp), %rax 

cmp $0, %rax
je zeroValue
cmp $1, %rax
je oneValue
jmp more

zeroValue:
addq $0, %r8
jmp end

oneValue:
addq $1, %r8
jmp end

more:
movq 16(%rbp), %rax
dec %rax
pushq %rax
call fibonacci
movq 16(%rbp), %rax
dec %rax
dec %rax
pushq %rax
call fibonacci

end:
mov %rbp, %rsp
pop %rbp
ret
```

f2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int fibonacci (int);
int main ()
{
    int n = 6;
    int res;
    res = fibonacci(n);
    printf ("N-th member of Fibonacci sequence is: %d", res);
    return 0;
}
```

To compiling and linking i am making these commands:

```
as f1.S -o f1.o

gcc f2.c -c -o f2.o

gcc f2.o f1.o -o program
```

Everything is OK till i am trying to run my exe file (program). I can not run it cause I've got message: Segmentation Fault. What am I doing wrong?
Fibonacci function is for sure OK cause I was using it in clean Assembler  and then it worked.

Comment: Where are the files?

Comment: And if you have crashes, then run in a debugger to try and locate *where* the crash is.

Comment: Sry that is my first message here and i accidentally sent it... Now is edited and i added codes. When im trying to run it in gdb i've got:
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040056f in more ()`

Comment: Seems like you should align the stack. Read online for more information.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. Also, comment your code, especially if you want others to help. That said, I can see you discard the result from the first recursive call, and the fault is probably due to stack overflow caused by wrong termination condition. Single step in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gdb you get SIGSEGV like this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
fibonacci () at f1.S:6
6   push %rax
```

What's more interesting is your backtrace (end of it):

```
(gdb) backtrace -10
#1048280 0x00007fffffffe6e0 in ?? ()
#1048281 0x000000000040056d in more () at f1.S:28
#1048282 0x00007fffffffe7fe in ?? ()
#1048283 0x00007fffffffe7ff in ?? ()
#1048284 0x00007fffffffe700 in ?? ()
#1048285 0x000000000040056d in more () at f1.S:28
#1048286 0x00007fffffffe7ff in ?? ()
#1048287 0x0000000000000006 in ?? ()
#1048288 0x00007fffffffe720 in ?? ()
#1048289 0x000000000040051f in main () at f2.c:7
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

So you managed to call your recursion 1 048 289 times...

Further more, after line 8 (`movq 16(%rbp), %rax`), you'll get:

```
(gdb) i r rax
rax            0x7fffffffe800   140737488349184
```

And from your function it looks like `rax` should be a counter.

Since you're using 64bit registers I assume you're running x86_64 architecture [which doesn't store arguments on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/1149736) but uses registries:

> If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used

```
(gdb) i r edi
edi            0x6  6
```

Your solution would probably run fine on [cdecl calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), but not on *Microsoft x64 calling convention* or *System V AMD64 ABI*.

So for example a way to get this done is (works for *System V AMD64 ABI*):

```asm
.global fibonacci
fibonacci:

push %rbp
push %rdi

cmp $0, %rdi
je zeroValue
cmp $1, %rdi
je oneValue
jmp more

zeroValue:
    movq $0, %rax
    jmp end

oneValue:
    movq $1, %rax
    jmp end

more:
    dec %rdi
    call fibonacci
    push %rax
    dec %rdi
    call fibonacci
    pop %r8
    add %r8, %rax

end:
    pop %rdi
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

Which goes like:

- store rbp
- store rdi
- if rdi == 0: return 0
- if rdi == 1: return 1
- decrease rdi
- call fibonacci
- store result on stack
- decrease rdi
- call fibonacci
- restore result to r8
- add r8 to result
- restore rdi
- restore rbp

And just out of curiosity, here's a version without recursion, just one loop (and few cases handling low values):

```
.global fibonacci
fibonacci:

cmp $2, %rdi # 2 and higher should be computer normally
jg compute

cmp $0, %rdi
jz zero 
mov $1, %rax # 1st and 2nd elements = 1
ret

zero:
    mov $0, %rax
    ret

compute:
    mov %rdi, %rcx  # Use cpu counter register
    sub $2, %rcx    # The first number that will come out of this loop
                    # is 2, so decrease number of iterations
    mov $1, %r8     # a = 1
    mov $1, %r9     # b = 1

begin_iter:
    mov %r9, %rax   # sum = b
    add %r8, %rax   # sum += a
    mov %r9, %r8    # a = b
    mov %rax, %r9   # b = a

    loop begin_iter

    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure how the C function will call your assembly function. so you can prepare your assembly function to deal with the call.

for example if the c call will not clean the stack after the assembly function return `stdcal` then you must clean the stack in the assembly code

EDIT: removed the notice on the registers syntax. thanks Vyktor

Comment: With intel syntax (without %) this would mean `rsp = rbp`, with at&t it's the opposite.